# How to get SKSpriteNode by physicsBody?

Tags: swift, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I extended `SKSpriteNode` with my own class to have more functions.

But how can I get this extended node when something 'hits' this node and `didBeginContact` is called?

Because `contact.bodyA` and `contact.bodyB` are physicsBody and parent of this is the game scene.

This is my subclass of SKSpriteNode:

```
class Orange: SKSpriteNode {
    ...

    func createPhysicsBody(){
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width / 2)
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        ...
    }
}
```

This is my didBeginContact code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact){    
    switch(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask + contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
        case orangeCategory + bulletCategory:
            contactOrangeBullet(contact.bodyA, bodyB: contact.bodyB)
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In `contactOrangeBullet` is just code that handles everything when this case happens. But I need more than `physicsBody`. I need the 'Orange' which `physicsBody` is just a part of.

Or do I understand something wrong and this is not possible because physicsBody does not stick to 'Orange' although it was created in there?

Answer (score 2):

So, here is an example of how you can get the node associated with the physics body.

```
var node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "theimage")

node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 6)

var copy = node.physicsBody
```

Now, I will get the SKNode associated with `copy`

```
var node = copy.node
```

So, all you have to do is call the property `node` on the physicsBody. Remember that the `node` property returns an `SKNode`, not `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am using at the moment. But this SKNode doesn't know anything about my `Orange` class functions and attributes.

Comment: I do it that way now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812108/how-to-know-which-skspritenode-is-affected-by-collision-detection-in-swift/31922288#31922288