# How to know which SKSpriteNode is affected by collision detection in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, object, sprite-kit, collision

**Situation:** I have two or more ships on my iOS screen. Both have different attributes like name, size, hitpoints and score points. They are displayed as `SKSpriteNodes` and each one has added a `physicsBody`.

At the moment those extra attributes are variables of an extended `SKSpriteNode` class.

```
import SpriteKit    
class ship: SKSpriteNode {
            var hitpoints: Int = nil?
            var score: Int = nil?

        func createPhysicsBody(){
            self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width / 2)
            self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            ...
        }
    }
```

In this 'game' you can shoot at those ships and as soon as a bullet hits a ship, you get points. 'Hits a ship' is detected by collision.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact){    
    switch(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask + contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
        case shipCategory + bulletCategory:
            contactShipBullet(contact.bodyA, bodyB: contact.bodyB)
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** Collision detection just returns a physicsBody and I do not know how to get my extended `SKSpriteNode` class just by this physicsBody.

**Thoughts:** Is it a correct way to extend `SKSpriteNode` to get my objects like a ship to life? When I add a ship to my screen it looks like:

```
var ship = Ship(ship(hitpoints: 1, score: 100), position: <CGPosition>)
self.addChild(ship)
```

Or is this just a wrong approach and there is a much better way to find out which object with stats so and so is hit by a bullet thru collision detection?

This question is similar to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772869/how-to-get-skspritenode-by-physicsbody) - I just want ask this in broader sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `SKPhysicsBody` has a property `node` which is the `SKNode` associated to the body. You just need to perform a `conditional cast` to your `Ship` class.

```
    if let ship = contact.bodyA.node as? Ship {
        // here you have your ship object of type Ship
        print("Score of this ship is: \(ship.score)!!!")
    }
```

Please note that the `Ship` node could be the one associated with `bodyB` so.

```
    if let ship = contact.bodyA.node as? Ship {
        // here you have your ship...
    } else if let ship = contact.bodyB.node as? Ship {
        // here you have your ship...
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Finally someone gave me the right solution - thank you alot. I am using now this line `var ship = bodyA.categoryBitMask == bubbleCategory ? bodyA.node as? Ship : bodyB.node as? Ship`. And this is the correct approach to save game object relevant data like score and hitpoints? I will test solution with several different game objects and as soon as everything works I will mark this as correct answer.