# How to call a designated initializer of the superclass SKPhysicsBody?

Tags: swift, initialization, skphysicsbody, extending

**Scenario:** Since I need to know hitpoints and score of my game objects, I want extend SKPhysicsBody with some more stats. I have asked some related questions alread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772869/how-to-get-skspritenode-by-physicsbody) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812108/how-to-know-which-skspritenode-is-affected-by-collision-detection-in-swift).

**Problem:** I get this error *"Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'SKPhysicsBody'"*. And I do not know what I am doing wrong. I did almost same with SKSpriteNode and `super.init` worked. But there I had the problem that collision detection only returns `physicsBody` and not SKSpriteNode.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Bubble: SKPhysicsBody {

    let bubbleSize = ["large": CGFloat(1.0), "medium": CGFloat(0.5), "small": CGFloat(0.25)]

    let playerCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 0
    let worldCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 1
    let bubbleCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 2
    let bulletCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 3

    var hitpoints: Int?
    var score: Int?

    init(bubble: (id: Int, name: String, scale: String, image: String, hitpoints: Int, score: Int)) {
        super.init(circleOfRadius: 50)
        self.hitpoints = bubble.hitpoints
        self.score = bubble.score

        self.dynamic = true
        self.friction = 0.5
        self.restitution = 1
        self.linearDamping = 0
        self.angularDamping = 0
        self.mass = 0.3
        self.categoryBitMask = bubbleCategory
        self.collisionBitMask = worldCategory
        self.contactTestBitMask = worldCategory | playerCategory
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Edit:** When I use `super.init()` I do not get any errors. But how can I set its size like `circleOfRadius` or `rectangleOfSize`? Normally it should work with `super.init(circleOfRadius: <CGFloat>)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initializer you are attempting to call is derived from conversion of the Objective C factory method:

```
+ (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithCircleOfRadius:(CGFloat)r;
```

By command clicking on the class in your code, you can see that it is presented to Swift as:

```
/*not inherited*/ init(circleOfRadius r: CGFloat)
```

For contrast, the UIView initializer:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

is seen in Swift as:

```
init(frame: CGRect)
```

without the `/*not inherited*/` comment.

The reason for the difference is that the factory method underlying the SKPhysicsBody initializer always returns a concrete instance of SKPhysicsBody, while initWithFrame is an instance method returning `instancetype`, allowing it to be used in subclass initialization.

Your subclass therefore cannot rely on any of the standard initializers for SKPhysicsBody.

Comment: So it works with `SKSpriteNode` but not with `SKPhysicsBody`. Dang - I have no clue where to save my game object attributes so that I can get them by physicsBody, because Swifts collision detection only returns them.

Comment: Yes, now I understand why this doesn't work. Gotta find another way to save my attributes to my game objects.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a dictionary of game objects with the physics bodies as keys.

Comment: Maybe you could write your suggestion (a little bit more in detail) [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105198/where-should-i-save-game-objects-attributes-hp-score-in-swift).